# Can't install plv8: /usr/include/postgresql/12/server/pg_config*.h': No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, linux-mint, plv8

Linux Mint 20.2, Postgres 9.6

I need to install **plv8**

I try this:

```
 wget https://github.com/plv8/plv8/archive/v2.0.0.tar.gz
 tar -xvzf v2.0.0.tar.gz
 cd plv8-2.0.0
 make static
 make install
```

But I get error:

```
cat: '/usr/include/postgresql/12/server/pg_config*.h': No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 1: test: -ge: unexpected operator
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
make -f Makefile.v8
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/alexeij/Downloads/plv8/plv8-2.0.0'
cat: '/usr/include/postgresql/12/server/pg_config*.h': No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 1: test: -ge: unexpected operator
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++11 -fno-rtti  -Ibuild/v8-git-mirror-5.4.500.43/include -Ibuild/v8-git-mirror-5.4.500.43 -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal  -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -fPIC -c -o plv8.o plv8.cc
make[1]: g++: Command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:85: plv8.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alexeij/Downloads/plv8/plv8-2.0.0'
make: *** [Makefile:145: static] Error 2
```

Comment: Read the instructions [Build](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/blob/r3.1alpha/docs/BUILDING.md), especially the section titled Building.

Answer (score 1):

Install the build tools and some common *-dev packages:

```
apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake gdb git libffi-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
```

Other specific *-dev packages are listed in the Build file.
You will also need to install the *-dev package for PostgreSQL. To find the exact package name you can use the apt-file utility to search for the missing header file:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search pg_config
```